# Can't connect after Tuleap install on Debian sid under docker

Tags: installation, debian, docker, tuleap

I have followed the instructions at http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/developer-guide/quick-start/run-tuleap.html, but hitting http://tuleap_web_1.tuleap-aio-dev.docker/ gives "Server not found". The first two points under "3.4. Troubleshooting" seem OK, but the third one gives ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" on both the `dig '*.docker', dig '*.tuleap-aio-dev.docker'` and `dig 'tuleap_web_1.tuleap-aio-dev.docker'` commands.

Unfortunately, there are no follow up tips for when these commands fail. I will add that if I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to lack of dnsdock working properly. The easiest way to go would be to capture the IP the web container:

`docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' tuleap_web_1`

and to set the result in your `/etc/hosts` like:

```
172.17.0.4    tuleap_web_1.tuleap-aio-dev.docker
```

You will have to update the IP address each time you start the container.

Comment: That works, thanks. I would like a more permantent solution (but this would do). I am looking at adding options to ExecStart in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, but I am wondering if it has anything to do with the docker change in default to using 172.17.42.x?

Comment: For a more permanent solution you should investigate why dnsdock is not working. One of the issue we have already seen is a bug in dnsdock it self (look at https://github.com/tonistiigi/dnsdock/issues/34) after having merged the 2 attached PR + relauch of dnsdock it might be better